# Setting the img src to be the img src on another website based on img id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Is it possible to get the img src from a completely different web page if you have the img ID and then use that as the img src on your own website?

That way, when the image changes on that other website, it will also change on yours.

So, for example, on www.abcdefg.com/1234567/ there is an image.
The img id for the image in question is "image-tag"

I would like to be able to get the src of that image by using the img id (image-tag) and use it as the img src on my own web page.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

CORS prevent you from sending an ajax request to fetch HTML from a different origin, but it is possible to fetch the other website from a server and extracts the image tag to get the image src.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = 'http://www.bamuel.com/';
$content = file_get_contents($link);
$first_step = explode( '<img id="epic article">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</img>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

You can possibly able todo it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

It does not go that way.

Let's say your desired id is

```
id = "image-tag"
```

and  `src = "http://www.abcdefg.com/1234567.png"`

you wish the line would look like this:

```
<img id="image-tag">
```

For it to get the source(src),

You could do this with JavaScript:

```
var image_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
var attr_val = image_tag.getAttribute('id')
if (attr_val == 'image-tag'){
   attr_val.src = "http://www.abcdefg.com/1234567.png";
}
```

This way, from your example, whenever you declare any `img` with `id = "image-tag"`, the source will automatically be referenced to the site as required.

Comment: But in the case in my question, I do not know the src of the img.  So I would not know what the value of attr_val.src would be